# what is the pysparkic way of doing for loop on spark df

Tags: pyspark

in pyspark what is the best way to do an operation for a id when a groupby does not apply. here is a sample code:

```
for id in [int(i.id) for i in df.select('id').distinct().collect()]:
    temp = df.where("id == {}".format(id))
    temp = temp.sort("date")
    my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id")
    temp = temp.withColumn("prev_transaction",lag(temp['date']).over(my_window))
    temp = temp.withColumn("diff", temp['date']-temp["prev_transaction"))
    temp = temp.where('day_diff > 0')
    #select a row and so on
```

whats the best way to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have transactions data frame you want to add previous transactions column to it.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')
df.withColumn('pre_transactions', F.collect_list('id') \
                    .over(windowSpec.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
```

Code above will add array column with previous transactions untill this transactions .But last transactions will be also added to array. You can remove last transaction by simple custom udf like:

```
remove_element = lambda l:  l[:-1]
remove_udf = udf(remove_element, ArrayType(StringType()))
```